# Mirroring to create a single polygon across the mirroring plane

Tags: modeling, mesh, mirror

I'd like to create a single triangle by mirroring one vertex exactly on the mirror plane and another vertex across the mirroring plane to create a single face. I've shown an example image. In this example, I've already applied the mirror modifier but it won't create a face across the mirror boundary.

[image: Mirroring Example]

I'm really hoping something like this is possible? I guess I could just leave this one triangle until the very end, then apply the mirror modifier and fill it in, but it would be nice if I could leave the mirror modifier in place and have it correctly construct this face. Is there a trick to doing this?

Answer (score 1):

The mirror modifier in your illustration is working exactly as it is designed to do. In this case, it is mirroring an edge. To complete a face, you need to add one more vertex, located at the intersection of a line perpendicular to the y axis, and the y axis, which passes through the vertex furthest from the y axis, and create the face. The easiest way to create this vertex in the illustrated figure is to extrude from the vertex at the far right to the y axis, constraining the extrusion to the x direction. If you do this, the mirror modifier will work the way you wish.

Comment: But then it will create two triangles and I just want one.

Comment: There would also be an edge that ran along the Y axis, which I also don't want. I'm basically trying to mirror polygons across the boundary without having a seam along the mirrored axis, if that makes sense.

Comment: Then I think you're trying to use the mirror modifier to do something it can't do, in this case, creating something (an edge) from nothing.

Comment: So is there some better way to do what I'm wanting to do? I suppose it would just have to involve post-processing, eh? Apply the mirror modifier and then fill in any holes that it didn't connect?

Comment: I don't know enough about your project or workflow design to know exactly what you are trying to do.

Comment: I'm just trying to make a symmetrical model without an edge all along the mirroring axis. In my example, I've shown the *single* triangle I'd like to create. If I followed your instructions, I'd end up with *two* triangles and an edge along the mirroring axis. The model I'm making will be shown in wireframe, and I think aesthetically it would look a lot better without a seam running the length of the mirroring axis, so that's what I'm trying to accomplish. Looks like it may not be possible in any straightforward manner, however.

Comment: @aardvarkk I don't think it's possible. I think it would be easier to model with the extra edge in the middle, then apply the mirror modifier and delete it once finished.